# Why last additions to VC++11 are not allowed in XP target'

Tags: visual-c++

I want to compile next line:

```
 R"(The String Data \ Stuff " )"
```

When target is windows XP (vc110_xp), it gives me compilation error; if the VC++ target is not Windows XP, compiler accepts the syntax.
¿Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [November 2012 Compiler CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx) is a *community technology preview*:  it's a preview for people to use and test with, but is not intended for production use (it does not come with a "Go Live" license).

[Visual Studio 2012 Update 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1-now-available.aspx) is an update for Visual Studio 2012 that is intended for production use.  This is the update that includes support for using Visual C++ 2012 to target Windows XP.

These are two different releases, made for two different purposes.  The November 2012 Compiler CTP was released before Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 was released, and it does not include the support for Windows XP (it only updates the compiler binaries, though, so you might be able to use some MSBuild magic to use the new preview compiler with the new Windows XP support libraries; doing so is not supported, though).